# Behavoiur doesn't get event about finish of fling

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

My custom Behavior can catch all scroll event. But if fling happens it doesn't get scroll events (because it is fling), gets start of fling event, and DON'T GET end of fling event. As result I can not do corresponding behavior.

What's wrong? How to catch event about fling was stopped?

```
    class MyCustomBehaviour(val context: Context, val attr: AttributeSet)
        : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<MyFloatingButton>(context, attr) {

        override fun layoutDependsOn(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: MyFloatingButton, dependency: View): Boolean {
            return when (dependency) {
                is Snackbar.SnackbarLayout -> true
                else -> super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency)
            }
        }

        override fun onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
                                         child: MyFloatingButton,
                                         directTargetChild: View,
                                         target: View,
                                         nestedScrollAxes: Int): Boolean {
            return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
        }

        override fun onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
                                    child: MyFloatingButton,
                                    target: View,
                                    dxConsumed: Int, dyConsumed: Int,
                                    dxUnconsumed: Int, dyUnconsumed: Int) {
            // got it when scroll happens
        }


        override fun onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
                                   child: MyFloatingButton,
                                   target: View,
                                   velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float, consumed: Boolean): Boolean {
            // got it when fling started
            return true;
        }

        override fun onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: MyFloatingButton, target: View) {
            // got it when scroll (not fling!) finished
            // but there is no event when fling finished. why??
        }
    }
```